# Socket io returns 404 Not Found on docker run

Tags: node.js, docker, socket.io

I am trying to build a chat application using SocketIO, Mongodb and NodeJS. The web application runs successfully on `:80` when I use:

> docker run -d --name mongo mongo
>
> docker run --name appname --link mongo:mongo -p 80:3000 -d docker_user/app

But SocketIO continues to send errors in browser console like:

`GET http://url/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MOH41PY 404 (Not Found)`

My `index.js` looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);

const https = require('https');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var request = require('request');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// Set Static path...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));


//Connect to mongo...
mongo.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017/team_chat_data', function(err,db){

  if(err){
  throw(err);
}

//Rest of logic...
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('Server started on port :3000');
});
```

Now, I am trying to connect to my server using my `index.html` with :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>     
// Connect to socket.io
var socket = io.connect('http://url:80');
// Check for connection
if(socket !== undefined){
console.log('Connected to socket...');
// Handle Output
socket.on('output', function(data){
console.log(data);
}); 
</script>
```

I am able to see the message *Connected to socket* in my browser console but then there are error messages like:

`GET http://url/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MOH41PY 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Socket.IO can't intercept requests starting with /socket.io/. This is because in your case the listener is app -- an Express handler. You have to make http be listener, so that Socket.IO will have access to request handling.

Try to replace

```
var express = require('express'); // line 1
```

with

```
var app = require('express')();
```

See docs for details: https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express

Alternatively you could try https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Node-http-server